# Fix keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Snowflake error

Tags: python, json, discord, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write a list of users from a discord server into a json using python, but I keep receiving this error.

[image]

Ideally I want to turn my dict `{Snowflake(USERID#): Member(user=User(id=Snowflake(USERID#), username='USERNAME', discriminator='#', bot=None), nick=None),`

Into a JSON file only containing the `bot=none` users in a format like this:

```json
{
    "USERID#1": {
        "Username": "USERNAME1"
  },
 "USERID#2": {
        "Username": "USERNAME2"
  },
...
}
```

**Edit:**

1. Error text is `TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Snowflake`
2. My code to initially pull the data into the dict and attempt to write it to the json is:

```py
    import interactions
    from interactions import Button, ButtonStyle, SelectMenu, SelectOption, ActionRow, spread_to_rows
    import json

    memberslist = await guild.get_all_members()
    print(memberslist)
    membersdict = {Member.id: Member for Member in memberslist}
    with open("playersbackup.json","w") as n:
      json.dump(membersdict,n, indent=4)
```

Comment: You aren't showing the code that you're using to retrieve the data or convert it to that dict that you're trying to JSON encode. It's hard to help.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: you will have to use `for`-loops and convert it to normal dictonary.

Comment: Updated to address the comments and suggestions with more information. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this sample bot which produced the json dumps you are looking for:

```py
from discord import Intents, Member, Guild
from discord.ext import commands
from os import environ
import json


class StackOverFlowAnswer(commands.Bot):
    def convert_member_to_dict(self, member: Member) -> dict:
        return {
            "user": member.id,
            "username": member.name,
            "discriminator": member.discriminator,
            "nick": member.nick,
        }

    def get_member_backup(self, guild: Guild) -> str:
        to_dict = self.convert_member_to_dict
        data = {user.id: to_dict(user) for user in filter(lambda member: not member.bot, guild.members)}
        return json.dumps(data, indent=4)

    def dump_data(self, data: str, filename: str = "players.json") -> None:
        with open(filename, "w") as file:
            file.write(data)


# Code beyond this point is for demonstrational purposes
# The above code produced the json structure that you desired




bot = StackOverFlowAnswer(command_prefix="?", intents=Intents.all())


@bot.command(aliases=["dump"])
async def _dump(ctx: commands.Context):
    assert ctx.guild is not None
    backup = bot.get_member_backup(ctx.guild)
    bot.dump_data(backup)
    await ctx.send(f"Wrote:\n{backup}")


bot.run(environ["DISCORD_TOKEN"])
```

The command output:
[image: command output]

Furthermore, here is the JSON file that was created:
[image: json output]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Member.id` is neither of the suggested data types. If the key is a custom data type, it should conform to *hashable*.

Implement `def __hash__(self):` and `def __eq__(self,other):` for the `Member.id` data type to see if it helps.

i.e.:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(str(self.id_num))

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.id_num == other.id_num
```